# Store scraped web links into array

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I am trying to store scraped web links into arrays so I will be able to use them later in my code. I have VBScript solution and was trying to convert it to VB.net without result. Can somebody give me hint?

In VBScript I have used `vbCrLf` to separate links.

I want to store links and print them to console at this stage just to make sure.

Here is my current code:

```
Imports HtmlAgilityPack

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim mainUrl As String = "https://www.nordicwater.com/products/waste-water/"
        Dim htmlDoc As HtmlDocument = New HtmlWeb().Load(mainUrl) '< - - - Load the webage into htmldocument

        Dim LinkArrays As String ' String to store the links
        Dim i As Integer = 1

        Dim srcs As HtmlNodeCollection = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul[@class='products-list-page']//a") '< - - - select nodes with links
        For Each src As HtmlNode In srcs

            ' Show links in console
            Console.WriteLine(src.Attributes("href").Value) '< - - - Print urls

            ' Store links in array
            LinkArrays &= src.Attributes("href").Value
            i += 1

        Next

        Console.Read()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`List(Of String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1) instead of an array. Using [`.ToArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.toarray) on the list you can get an string array for later use:

```
Imports HtmlAgilityPack

Sub Main()
    Dim mainUrl As String = "https://www.nordicwater.com/products/waste-water/"
    Dim htmlDoc As HtmlDocument = New HtmlWeb().Load(mainUrl) '< - - - Load the webage into htmldocument

    Dim listLinks As New List(Of String)

    Dim srcs As HtmlNodeCollection = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul[@class='products-list-page']//a") '< - - - select nodes with links
    For Each src As HtmlNode In srcs

        ' Show links in console
        Console.WriteLine(src.Attributes("href").Value) '< - - - Print urls

        ' Store links in array
        listLinks.Add(src.Attributes("href").Value)
    Next

    'you can get the array from the list.
    Dim arrayLinks() As String = listLinks.ToArray()

    Console.Read()
End Sub
```